# Access Denied while scraping seekingAlpha transcript with beautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape earning calls transcript using beautifulSoup. I was able to extract first time but later it is giving me access denied error. I have tried randomizing the user agents but it is not working

**Code to randomize user agents **

```
import random
user_agent_list = [
   #Chrome
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
    #Firefox
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)'
]
user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
```

**Code used to extract transcript**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
parse_site = 'https://seekingalpha.com/article/4333315-swiss-re-ag-ssref-2019-annual-report-conference-call-transcript?part=single'
html_content = requests.get(parse_site, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent}).text
print (BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml'))
```

Error: Access to this page has been denied.

Comment: works good for me.

Comment: what you want to extract ? show example

Comment: It works the first time but when I rerun it, it is giving access denied error.

Comment: I want to extract the transcript (the content between article tags) and I was able to run it only once. Second time, it is giving errors.

Comment: @user1048278 something like `John Dacey`?

Comment: Yes I will be extracting all participant names from the page into a list. John dacey, Edi Schmid etc

Comment: Did you try the script suggested below @user1048278?

Comment: @SIM, I tried but the access denied message is happening at soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml") level itself so unable to proceed to next step. It earlier ran on Google colab but it isn't running even on that. Do you think it is because I am on my office network?

Comment: @user1048278 Were you able to get this to work?